# TextField displays -[UIWindow endDisablingInterfaceAutorotationAnimated:] error when keyboard is long pressed (SwiftUI)

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui

Whenever I long-press on a key in the iOS keyboard to show alternative keys, I get the following error:

```
2020-03-09 21:44:42.669194-0400 TestProject[10220:731641] 
-[UIWindow endDisablingInterfaceAutorotationAnimated:] called on 
<UIRemoteKeyboardWindow: 0x7ff98204fc00; frame = (0 0; 320 568); 
opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x6000020980e0>> 
without matching -beginDisablingInterfaceAutorotation. Ignoring.
```

This even happens on a new project. Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var testing: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Hello, World!", text: $testing)
    }
}
```

I tried searching for a solution online, but everyone is having this problem when they are trying to dynamically hide the keyboard, which is not my case. Does anyone have any idea why I get this error?

P.S. I am working on XCode Version 11.3.1 (11C504).

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely not an error. 
It is just a debug message thrown into the console which you can safely ignore.